# Missing parameter type for expanded function for Unit in scala

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I'm trying to wrap some actor receive code in db transaction to build idempotent persistent view that handles events by updating the information in database.

```
class TrajectoryView extends IdempotentView {


  override def viewId: String = "trajectoryView"

  override def persistenceId: String = "sample-id-1"

  override def handleEvent(event: Event): Unit = {
      case ProcessDetectedEvent(time, processData, id, activityType) =>
        val coords = Db.save(processData.coordinates)
        Db.save(CoordinatesWrapper(id, coords))

      case ProcessUpdatedEvent(id, processData, time) =>
        val coords = Db.save(processData.coordinates)
        Db.save(CoordinatesWrapper(id, coords))
  }
}

abstract class IdempotentView extends PersistentView {

  def handleEvent(event: Event): Unit = ???
  var maxSeenSeqNumber = Db.query[SeqNumberWrapper].fetchOne().getOrElse(SeqNumberWrapper(0, viewId)).seqNumber

  def receive: Receive = {
    case event: Event =>
      if (lastSequenceNr > maxSeenSeqNumber) {
        Db.transaction {
          Db.save(SeqNumberWrapper(lastSequenceNr, viewId))
          handleEvent(event)
        }
      }

    case _: Unit =>
      println("Unknown message")
  }
}



Error:(22, 50) missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) 

Expected type was: Unit   override def handleEvent(event: Event): Unit = {
```

What should I do? I don't event understand what this error means exactly. From my point of view I have written all types, the compiler doesn't need to infer anything.

Answer (score 4):

Choose one of

```
override def handleEvent:  Event => Unit = {
...
}
```

or

```
override def handleEvent(event: Event): Unit = event match {
...
}
```

If more precisely your code inside braces is suitable for defining `PartialFunction[T,Unit]` which is convertible to `Unit`. So generally your code  is correct, but compiler could not infer type `T` and whines about it. But if it could result would be a function returning another function and not what you are expecting.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I would spent the whole day reading scala docs to solve this without your help.